# AWS S3 bucket policy - how to allow access only from my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a paperclip text file attachment (in Rails).

My bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to restrict access to these actions to only be allowed when the request comes from my website. Is it simply a case of updating this to: "Principal": {"AWS": "mywebsite.com"} ?

Answer (score 16):

You can check some examples in [S3 Documentations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html)

To restrict the access from your web site, you can use the condition on **Referrer**:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests referred by www.mysite.com and mysite.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "aws:Referer":[
            " http://www.mysite.com/*",
            " http://mysite.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This prevents me opening the files from my site unfortunately

Comment: Check that you spelled it right: aws:Referer—Same as the HTTP referer field. Check also that your site URL is sent in the right format. Remove the condition, and check the headers of the images.

Comment: How do I check the format my site URL is sent in? I can't open paperclip attachments from the site whenever I put the referrer in :-(

Comment: Use for example Chrome Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: Isn't there a red flag here that **direct traffic** hitting the website won't see any assets load (since the referer wouldn't be set to that particular website at that point in time)

Answer (score 6):

Bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000:user/example-user" // IAM User ARN
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-example/*", // bucket ARN
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://example.com/*" // Website link
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```